# Man dies in space but his head is preserved, later reanimated with a robotic body

Tags: story-identification, novel, space

I read this book about 10 years ago. It's about a guy that travels to space to build the first space station (the first of the habitat colonies). An accident happens and his head is cut off but preserved by its exposure to space. Decades later he is brought back to life with a robot body, finds out his son (think his name was Jack) died in his 50's and his daughter is now old with grandchildren and the guy goes to visit her and when she is told who he is she regresses to a child like state(since this was the last time she saw her father) and she says the line "Jack daddy is home" mistaking her grandson or maybe great grandson for her brother and they proceed to have dinner with a person playing a role as her family from when she was a child(because she's mentally fragile i think or it could be because she was old). The only other thing I remember is something about the sun going to go out.

Anyone know what the name of the book is?

Comment: Interesting. Any other details such as country it was published in, description of the front cover, page count?

Comment: can't remember, but the book should have been 200+ pages

Comment: it should be published in the US, because i think i got it from a book nook

Comment: Sounds like Futurama!

Comment: @Lavenchi Was it a relatively new book when you read it?

Comment: @Anthony Grist, Not entirely sure but i seem to remember it being a kind of old looking book maybe from the early 90's or so

Comment: The beginning of your description sounds like Edmund Cooper's _The Tenth Planet_, but the rest doesn't match.

Comment: Some similar points to Sun's End by Richard A Lupoff. but Quiet a few different so slow to put it as an answer

Comment: @AidanO thanks alot that is the book i'm looking for

Answer (score 7):

Based on feedback in comments, it's *[Sun's End](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3437259-sun-s-end)* by Richard A Lupoff. It's been a while since I read it but basically it's a story about an astronaut who gets injured and is unconscious for about 80 years. When he wakes up, he discovers that he's been rebuilt. At the end of it, he goes off into space by himself on a sled, only to discover that someone else is also inside his mind.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe Neil R. Jones' "[The Jameson Satellite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neil_R._Jones)":

> "Jameson was obsessed with the idea of perfectly preserving his body
>   after death and succeeded by having it launched into space in a small
>   capsule. Jameson's body survived for 40,000,000 years, where it was
>   found orbiting a dead planet Earth by a passing Zorome exploration
>   ship...The Zoromes discovered that Jameson's body had been so well
>   preserved that they were able to repair his brain, incorporate it into
>   a Zorome machine body and restart it. The professor joined their crew
>   and, over the course of the series, participated in many adventures,
>   even visiting Zor, the Zorome homeworld, where he met biological
>   Zoromes. The professor eventually rose to command his own crew of
>   machine men on a new Zorome exploration ship.

It's a pretty old story published in 1931, but might have been re-vamped.